# Remove Active Tag Display in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

It is bothering me so much. In my previous PHPstorm, it did not display the active HTML tag. Can anybody tell me how to disable / hide that tool window.

[image: How to remove HTML tag]

My phpstorm version is 2016.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known as the breadcrumb menu for current code position. For example in your image you are in the position of class Display -> method Display() (constructor) -> member anonymous ActionListner -> method actionPerformed() -> member anonymous SwingWorker. (should be verified)

To disable it from showing, Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance

And Find and un-tick 'Show breadcrumbs'.

You might need to restart the editor, to take this effect into action.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It was bothering me so much.
Helped me